# get data from asp page

Tags: javascript, html, perl, web-scraping

I am wondering if there is anyway to grab the html that is generated from an ASP page. I am trying to pull a table from the page, and I foolishly used a static html page so I would not have to be constantly querying the server where this page resides while I tested out my code. The javascript code I wrote to grab to unlabeled table from the page works. Then when I put it into practice with the real page and found that the ASP page does not generate a viewable page with a jquery .get request on the URL.

Is there any way to query the page for the table I need so that the ASP page returns a valid page on request?

(I am also limited to using javascript and perl for this, the server where this will reside will not run php and I have no desire to learn ASP.NET to solve this by adding to the issue of proprietary software)

Answer (score 1):

Use Perl's LWP module to query the ASP.NET page to get the required information.  I would open the target page in a web browser while doing a WireShark trace so you can tell exactly how the browser is calling the page and getting the table information, and then perform the same call with LWP.

Answer (score 0):

Is the page that is trying to get the table on the same domain?  It needs to be.  If not you have to use a proxy or XMLHttpRequest Level 2 access control headers.

Comment: I believe it is on the same domain. I have found I am getting a 401 unauthorized response from my ajax request to the page.